# How to read an XML message delivered by a 3rd party at a URL with POST?

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, callback

A 3rd party APP delivers a XML message at a URL. I want to be able to read and operate with that message at WordPress.

I believe that `SimpleXMLElement` is the key, rather than creating a class. But many errors are returned based on what I put as a parameter.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'webhook', '/v1', array(
    'methods'  => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'myfunction',
  ));
});

function myfunction () {

    $mymessage = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

    $messageType = $mymessage->cgCallback[0]->existingField;

    echo $messageType ;
}
```

`$mymessage = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);` -> Returns "Undefined variable: xmlstr"

`$mymessage = new SimpleXMLElement($data);` -> Returns "Uncaught TypeError: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string"

`$mymessage = new SimpleXMLElement($message);` -> Returns "Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML"

Comment: try adding the variable as a parameter to your function - like so: `function myfunction ($xmlstr) {...}`

Comment: Thanks RamRaider. With

`function myfunction ($xmlstr) {
    $mymessage = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);`

returns "Uncaught TypeError: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string"

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the value you pass to this function?

Comment: Hi Nigel, I do not have any other code than that. I thought it should be enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got the solution: This will not work with `SimpleXMLElement` but with `simplexml_load_string` and requires `file_get_contents('php://input')`:

```
function myfunction () {

    $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($postData);

    $messageType = $xml->header[0]->existingField;

    echo $messageType ;
}
```